# TableView cell not scrolled on top after 3rd section in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I want scroll table view cell on top after clicked on cell, It is working up to 1 and 2 section but after that cell hidden behind "Keyboard".

```
- (void)scrollCellOnTop:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if(IS_IOS7)
{

self.supplierDetailTable .contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(SCREEN_X,SCREEN_Y,  self.supplierDetailTable.bounds.size.height-50, 0);

}
else
{

self.supplierDetailTable .contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(SCREEN_X, SCREEN_Y,  self.supplierDetailTable.bounds.size.height*tableInsetFraction, 0);

}

[ self.supplierDetailTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

}
```

Please give me a solution if you have.

Answer (score 0):

In order to scroll to a row in table view, you should do like below instead:

```
NSIndexPath *showOnTop = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row_index inSection:section_index];
[table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:showOnTop atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace line:

```
[ self.supplierDetailTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

with:

```
 NSIndexPath *iP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:indexPath.section];
[self.supplierDetailTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:iP atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```